# Getting HTML 5 based VR apps to display in Daydream

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, google-vr, daydream

How ready is the Daydream for VR apps built in HTML5?

I got my Daydream a few days ago. I set up a node server and put together a WebGL website using babylon.js, and it all works nicely on my PC. But I have trouble getting it to display in the headset.

For one, the Daydream app has no web browser and only features curated content. If I turn of NFC and launch a regular browser, the moment my phone slots into the headset, the phone thinks I touched the screen and it all goes haywire because the browser thinks I touched the URL bar. Also, without the NFC, the pointer device doesn't work.

Anyone have any experience displaying a regular WebGL website in the Daydream app? There's a Chrome Dev version, which apparently is VR ready but it doesn't show up as an app in the Daydream app.

My next attempts will be to force full-screen to get rid of the URL bar issue or use a Cordova wrapper, but any pointers would be much appreciated.

---

EDITED: How do I test WebGL HTML 5 pages in Daydream?  Isn't that a dev question?  :( I've got my webapp, I've got my node server, but I can't get it up and running in VR mode on the Daydrem.

Comment: Seems like a great thing to ask on Quora or twitter, but not StackOverflow - you're soliciting opinions on a product. Off-topic.

Comment: I think there is a dev question in there, just needs to be re-worded

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve the issue by turning off NFC on the phone so the Daydream app doesn't auto-launch and putting the HTML 5 page in a Cordova wrapper.